# How to use -pip- to install packages that can work with Anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install some additional packages that do not come with Anaconda. All of these packages can be installed using `pip install PackageName`. However, when I type this command at the Anaconda Command Prompt, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python27\python.exe
" "C:\python27\scripts\pip.exe" install MechanicalSoup'
```

I also tried to run the command from the python interpreter after `import pip` but that also did not work (I got a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`).

I am a noob and understand that this might be a very basic question so thanks for your help in advance!

PS: I am using Windows 7, 64 bit, conda version: 3.7.1 and python version: 2.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @heinzchr's and @mmann's suggestions I was able to piece together the problem. I already had a version of Python 2.7 saved at `C:\Python27` and I had to remove this from the Path `(My Computer's properties> Advanced system settings> System variables> Path)`. I can now use `pip install` from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

When installing anaconda, you are asked if you want to include the installed python to your system PATH variable. Make sure you have it in your PATH. If everything is set up correct, you can run pip from your regular command prompt aswell.

Comment: Thanks. I have `C:\Anaconda` in my `System variables> Path` but can neither run pip from the Anaconda command prompt nor from Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around the use of pip

From the anaconda terminal window you can run:

```
conda install PackageName
```

Because MechanicalSoup isn't in one of anaconda's package channels you will have to do a bit of editing
See instructions near the bottom [on their blog](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify where on the blog these instructions can be found? Are you suggesting carefully reading the section on 'Rolling your own packages'?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for Python packages not added to current channels in anaconda, try https://conda-forge.org/ For example, if you want to install MechanicalSoup you'll find it at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mechanicalsoup and use the -c option to tell conda the channel to use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mechanicalsoup
```